# Javascript : Set values in HTML Form hidden input fields

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Using javascript / jquery. 
I want to do this for every field that starts with

> query.

```
queryForm['Foo'].value = queryForm['query.Foo'].value;
queryForm['Bar'].value = queryForm['query.Bar'].value;
queryForm['Baz'].value = queryForm['query.Baz'].value;

queryForm.submit();
```

And only if the queryForm['Foo'] exists.

Context: (You don't need to know this to answer my question, but it nice to know the context)

Above question is because of a fix / hack. Because I put the original Model in the ViewModel. Now Query is in the QueryViewModel.

```
@model QA.ViewModels.QueryViewModel
@using QA.ViewModels
@using QA.Enums
@{ 
    var query = Model.Query;
}
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Required(model => query.Foo, "Describe the facts and circumstances that are relevant to the query", true, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => query.Foo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control qa-tinymce-content" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => query.Foo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.Hidden("Foo")
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use a "hack"; just fix your code so that it works properly in the first place. Trying to do something like this with JavaScript to cover for a mistake in the code is just a bad idea all around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading closely at what you did here: you put the old ViewModel in a new ViewModel and you do not want to rename the fieldnames in the partials.

Then why don't you add the needed fieldnames to the new ViewModel?

```
public Query Query { get; set; }

#region Variabeles in Query you do not wish to rename in the partial views.

public string Foo {
    get { return Query.Foo; }
    set { Query.Foo = value; }
}

#endregion
```

Comment: I will test this and see if it works for me. Seems like the most easy way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your hack could be easily done with simple javascript like the following (not tested) :

```
for (let propertyName in queryForm){
 if(!queryForm.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) || propertyName.indexOf("query.") !== 0){
   continue;
 }
 let shortPropertyName = propertyName.substring(6);
 if(!queryForm.hasOwnProperty(shortPropertyName)){
   continue;
 }
 queryForm[shortPropertyName].value = queryForm[propertyName].value;

 //if you want to delete the 'long' property:
 // delete queryForm[propertyName];
}
//// (use let or var at your preference)
```

But, you should really ask yourself **why you would want to do such things !**

IMHO, you would better go with a **proper and tidy model for your view**.